# Считывание текста. Исполнять посимвольно в цикле

Tags: c++

Вводится последовательность символов, которая завершается символом точка. Определить является ли данная последовательность символов правильным изображением целого 16 - ного числа

Вопрос в том что я не знаю как задать программе то, что после неправильного символа при вводе правильного значение не менялось на true.
Ну непример ввожу:
0
A
C - пока что все идет правильно, число пока что все еще 16 - ное,
K - ввожу неправильный символ, число перестает быть 16 - ным,
Y - все еще не 16 - ное,
1 - и при вводе правильного символа, програма думает что число вновь стало 16 - ным.

Как мне сказать програме что когда вводится неправильный символ,то число больше не может быть 16 - ным?

Comment: А вопрос-то в чем? Что не получается?

Answer (score 0):

> Как мне сказать програме что когда вводится неправильный символ,то
>   число больше не может быть 16 - ным?

В вашем варианте можно сразу выдавать сообщение об ошибке и прерывать выполнение цикла ввода (с помощью *break*)

```
        объявить массив для числа
ЧТЕНИЕ: чтение символа из консоли
        если символ не равен '.' или 0...9 или [a...f или A...F] сообщить об ошибке и ПРЕРВАТЬ цикл
        сохранить символ в массив
        если символ не точка повторить в ЧТЕНИЕ

        если длина массива > 1 показать "введенное число ="
        иначе сообщить "число не введено"
```

Если хотите дать пользователю исключить ошибку, то просто игнорируйте ошибочные символы... Но тут возникнет необходимость выдать предупреждение о неверном символе и после него выдать в консоль уже введенную части числа для продолжения... вы отвлечетесь от задачи, хотя начинание было бы хорошее.
 
Классически, такая задача решается в два этапа:
 
- ввод цепочки символов до точки, без ограничений и проверок;
- на втором этапе проверятся введенное число и сообщается результат.